# I have full service but all my messages refuse to send?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sms

Yesterday I encountered a problem with my phone: I have full service and I can make phone calls, download, and use internet without a problem. I can also receive messages, but anytime I try to send it seems as if it doesn't even make an effort trying to send. It instantly says 'message not sent'. I have factory reset my phone 3 times since then.

I can't figure out what could cause this....its really frustrating...please help.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like your SMS settings are wrong. Most likely the [SMSC (Short Message Service Center)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_message_service_center) number is not set. Check your settings with the one your provider/carrier tells you to set.